# Изменить положение google map при загрузке в div

Tags: javascript, css3, api, google-maps-api, google-maps

Использую api google maps для отображение кастомной карты на сайте. Стоит маркер с координатами. Но карта грузится так, что маркер по центру блока. Как сделать так, чтобы карта была смещена в сторону? Скажем, чтобы маркер всегда был выровнен по левому краю.

[image: как сейчас]

[image: надо, чтобы было так после загрузки страницы.]

Answer (score 1):

Укажите координаты центра карты с помощью объекта center, примерно вот так:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
   zoom: 8
});
```